# Spring data elasticsearch - Eagerly load @Entity nested set

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Given this entity:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "foo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
private Instant createdDate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and this repository interface:

```
public interface FooSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Foo, Long> {}
```

How can I get the **bars** to be eagerly loaded when calling `Iterable<T> search(QueryBuilder var1);`. I thought this might work:

```
public interface FooSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Foo, Long> {

@Override
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"bars"})
Iterable<Foo> search(QueryBuilder queryBuilder);
}
```

... as per [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling), but it doesn't appear to work as expected i.e. ***bars*** not retrieved, but createdDate is.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks